# Shut down dialog in wrong language - MBP High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: high-sierra, language, internationalization

My Preferred & Primary language is set to English (The region is however set to Germany) as shown in the image below.

[image]

When I try to shut down or restart, I am presented a dialog in German language.

[image]

I have tried to solve this by running `sudo languagesetup` in the terminal to set the lang by selecting `Use English for the main language` then restarting. This had no effect.

Running `defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale` in the terminal outputs `en_DE`

Comment: Interestingly enough, the shutdown dialog is mixed English and German. Can you please run the following in the command line: "defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale"(without the quotes) and post the result?

Comment: Results in: `en_DE`